# when there is no data available on yahoo finance, is it possible to return N/A instead of there being an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I'm trying to collect several pieces of data for a company at one time, yet one piece being missing results in an error. Is it possible to prevent this by returning 'N/A' instead?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas
comp = yf.Ticker("ERO")
print(comp.info['industry'], comp.info['sector'], 
comp.info['currentPrice'],comp.info['targetMeanPrice'])
```

this returns the error

```
"print(comp.info['industry'], comp.info['sector'], 
comp.info['currentPrice'],comp.info['targetMeanPrice'])
KeyError: 'targetMeanPrice'"
```

is it possible to return N/A (there is no target price available on yahoo finance) and the 3 other pieces of data, rather than there being an error?

Comment: Use try/except statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_target_price(comp):
    try: 
        return yf.Ticker(comp).info['targetMeanPrice']
    except:
        return pandas.NA

get_target_price('AAPL') # 188.47
get_target_price('ERO') # <NA>
```